# Can't go back if QLPreviewController is pushed to NavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, qlpreviewcontroller

I am trying to edit PDF with QLPreviewController. I am pushing the QLPreviewController to the navigation stack and it works fine. But if I annotate the PDF and try to come back to previous controller, it's not working. The back button grays out after one tap then just gets stuck. Can you please let me know what I'm missing here?[image: d]

Here is the code:

```
func openPDF(file:FileModel){
        selectedFile = file
        
        let previewController = CustomQLViewController()
        previewController.file = self.selectedFile
        previewController.dataSource = self
        previewController.delegate = self
        
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(previewController, animated: true)

       
    }
func numberOfPreviewItems(in controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
        //return getFileURLFromFileModel()! as QLPreviewItem
        let previeItem = PreviewItem(url: getFileURLFromFileModel(), title: selectedFile?.name)
        return previeItem
    }
    
func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, editingModeFor previewItem: QLPreviewItem) -> QLPreviewItemEditingMode {
        return .updateContents
    }

func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, didUpdateContentsOf previewItem: QLPreviewItem) {
        print("updated")
        
    }

func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, didSaveEditedCopyOf previewItem: QLPreviewItem, at modifiedContentsURL: URL) {
        
    }
```

Comment: What is `CustomQLViewController`? Show the declaration of that class and how it makes use of `QLPreviewController`. You might want to present `CustomQLViewController` instead of pushing it.

Comment: ```CustomQLViewController``` doesn't have any code as of now. I had plans put some customisation. Challenge with presenting ```CustomQLViewController``` is, the theme of the navigation bar gets removed. I tried all possible solutions available in internet. But pushing works quite well.

Comment: Is `CustomQLViewController` just an empty subclass of `QLPreviewController`?

Comment: Yes, till now it's an empty subclass. I have plans for more logic to add but for now it's just an empty subclass.